# CTRL keys not working in Linux and Windows

Tags: linux, windows-8, keyboard, ctrl

Two or three months ago both laptop <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys stopped working. It is not a use problem since one key has been used more than the other and both are not working.

At first, both keys started working again pressing them hard or after plugging an external keyboard. Today I tried using `showkey` on Linux to see if the OS could see the input but seems that the signal from the keys is not read from the computer.

Do you know any way that can help me troubleshoot?

Comment: You already have. If you will provide the model number of the laptop from the serial number sticker (other model numbers don't help us find manuals) and add the make and model number by clicking [edit], we may be able to find the hardware manual for you. Please do not use Add Comment; instead, put that information in the original question, please, with [edit].

Comment: Since it's both OS's, it's almost certainly a hardware issue, e.g. loose plug or intermittent trace. You can open the laptop and try to fix it, or just use an external keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You have done all the troubleshooting necessary.  By using two operating systems, you have shown is not a driver, setting, or, software that is causing the issue.  This is confirmed by the fact that using a different keyboard, the problem is no longer present.

It *might* be possible to fix.  Typically keyboards are so cheap they are not worth the effort.

If this is a laptop, you will have to get a replacement keyboard from the manufacturer.  Be sure to purchase the proper localization of the keyboard, so that it fits and has the proper keys for your area.